# How can I refresh a JPanel in a JTabbedPane only if that tab is the one that is visible?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a pane that I need to rebuild the contents of and then swap it with the current panel, but only if it's the current tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
final int nTabIndex = myTabbedPane.indexOfTabComponent( myPanel );
final boolean bIsVisible = myTabbedPane.isEnabledAt( nTabIndex );
if ( bIsVisible ) {
    // Do stuff with myPanel
    myPanel.repaint();
}
```